# Static TableView through StoryBoard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have designed a long static tableview from storyboard by taking UITableViewController. I have assigned .h and .m file to UITableViewController and removed all datasource and delegate functions from .m file but when i'm scrolling my tableview its getting crashed. Don't know how. Please if anybody knows help me sort out this bug. Thanks in Advance :-)

Comment: did u set their delegates as well in storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

I tried creating long static TableView using storyboard and it is working fine for me.You can refer following link.

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_an_Xcode_Storyboard_to_Create_a_Static_Table_View